# can we build controller and model classes into seperate jar file and add that jar file as a dependency to another project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, jar

Normally in our spring MVC projects, we have atleast config, model, controller packages.my problem is can we build these model and controller directories separately as a jar file and add the resulted jar file to any another project.so that we can get rid of some coding and simplify it

Can we use @ComponantScan annotation to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use `Maven` .(
If you are not familiar wtih maven read this , its quite simple- https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html )

Follow below steps

1. Create a Maven main project with `packaging` `pom` in pom.xml file
2. Then create a maven module for this main project with packaging
   `JAR` where your model is placed.
3. Create another module with packaging `war` and add `dependency` of
   module we have created in second step to this project.

Now you build the `war` project module and `jar` of first module will automatically added into `war`

For the component scan question , while creating the different maven modules keep a common structure for `packages`

For example , You can use `com.app` as base package name and scan this `com.app` for beans using `componentscan`. packages in maven modules could be like this `com.app.controller, com.app.model` etc

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add the jar files to another project. You just need to add the jar files in the classpath. First create the jar file of the required package with help of eclipse export option:

1. Right click on the package and select export.
2. Go to Java and select JAR file
3. Give a name to your jar file and continue to click next until the jar is created.

Then make a new folder under the other project in eclipse. Copy and paste that jar file in this folder. Right click on that jar file -> Build Path -> Add to build path. Now you should be able to use those controllers. Just give the correct full package name that you have exported in the @ComponantScan annotation. Let me know if any issue.